# Create Task in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to create a task to create a clone table from one database to another and refresh daily.

```
CREATE TASK TASK_DELETE
WAREHOUSE = TEST
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 10 11 * * * America/Los_Angeles'
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST2."PUBLIC"."DELETE"
CLONE TEST1."PUBLIC"."DELETE";
```

I'm getting error message: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected 'Create'.
Does anyone know the issue with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `AS`

It should be

```
CREATE TASK TASK_DELETE
WAREHOUSE = TEST
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 10 11 * * * America/Los_Angeles'
AS CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST2."PUBLIC"."DELETE"
   CLONE TEST1."PUBLIC"."DELETE";
```

Comment: I added 'AS' before the CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE.  I'm getting another error message: Cannot perform CREATE TASK. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.  The database will be changing from TEST1 to TEST2, so I'm not sure if USE DATABASE call is a good idea.

Comment: Never mind.  I selected database and code ran successfully on the snowflake worksheet. Thanks!